# "operation is not supported for this type of object" ODBC error from running SQL pass through query

Tags: ms-access, dao, pass-through

I'm putting this specific item in here because I ended up somewhere completely different on StackOverflow, and don't see this specific answer anywhere.

I was getting an "ODBC error" back from running an MS Access report using an SQL passthrough query, and dao.Errors contained "Operation is not supported for this type of object"

Answer (score 0):

This error is also returned from an SQL pass through query when the query throws an error because a sub query return multiple values

In my case, the stored procedure was performing some updates on the table variable and using a subquery for totalling

e.g.  UPDATE T SET X = (SELECT Y FROM Z WHERE Z.A = T.A)  and A happens to appear twice in Z